# SuiteTalk - Issue creating ItemReceipt

Tags: web-services, soap, netsuite, suitetalk

I've been working on a "kind" of integration with NetSuite. We are using Suitetalk/SOAP webservices in order to pull and push some data, basic stuff only as I'm not a netsuite expert.

It's been working good pulling data from Netsuite and pushing (adding) vendorBill only. At this point everything is working good.

But then I was requested to add (create) purchase orders and also itemReceipts.

I've managed to create purchase order but I'm struggling trying to create the itemReceipt. When I send it to Netsuite I get the error "Adding new line to sublist expense is not allowed.".

Follow below the request and the response xml.

Can someone help me to spot what I am doing wrong? what is missing?

Thank you very much. Cheers.

**REQUEST**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


-<soap:Header>


-<preferences xmlns="urn:messages_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">

<warningAsError>false</warningAsError>

<ignoreReadOnlyFields>true</ignoreReadOnlyFields>

</preferences>


-<tokenPassport xmlns="urn:messages_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">

<account xmlns="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">1111111_SB1</account>

<consumerKey xmlns="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">****************************************************************</consumerKey>

<token xmlns="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">****************************************************************</token>

<nonce xmlns="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">1111100</nonce>

<timestamp xmlns="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">11111899</timestamp>

<signature xmlns="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" algorithm="HMAC-SHA1">****************************</signature>

</tokenPassport>

</soap:Header>


-<soap:Body>


-<add xmlns="urn:messages_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">


-<record xmlns:q1="urn:purchases_2019_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xsi:type="q1:ItemReceipt">

<q1:entity type="vendor" internalId="19918834"/>

<q1:subsidiary internalId="15"/>

<q1:createdFrom type="purchaseOrder" internalId="28854986"/>

<q1:tranDate>2020-01-31T08:21:38.7482415Z</q1:tranDate>

<q1:memo>test memo</q1:memo>

<q1:currency type="currency" internalId="1"/>


-<q1:itemList>


-<q1:item>

<q1:itemReceive>true</q1:itemReceive>

<q1:item type="inventoryItem" internalId="1238"/>

<q1:location type="location" internalId="26"/>

<q1:quantity>1</q1:quantity>

<q1:rate>200</q1:rate>

</q1:item>

</q1:itemList>


-<q1:expenseList>


-<q1:expense>

<q1:markReceived>true</q1:markReceived>

<q1:account>117</q1:account>

<q1:amount>0</q1:amount>

</q1:expense>

</q1:expenseList>

</record>

</add>

</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

**RESPONSE**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


-<soapenv:Header>


-<platformMsgs:documentInfo xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">

<platformMsgs:nsId>WEBSERVICES_1111111_SB1_013120208906514922222545436_466a0e814</platformMsgs:nsId>

</platformMsgs:documentInfo>

</soapenv:Header>


-<soapenv:Body>


-<addResponse xmlns="urn:messages_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">


-<writeResponse>


-<platformCore:status xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" isSuccess="false">


-<platformCore:statusDetail type="ERROR">

<platformCore:code>USER_ERROR</platformCore:code>

<platformCore:message>Adding new line to sublist expense is not allowed.</platformCore:message>

</platformCore:statusDetail>

</platformCore:status>

</writeResponse>

</addResponse>

</soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: You may want to check out this Slack community for help with this one: http://opensuite-slackin.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but anyone else finding themselves here. Its because the order line was not supplied. If you don't supply it NS thinks you are creating a new line which you are not allwoed to do.